# Bought a new router and yarn add/npm install stopped working due to timeout. I need to add entries to /etc/hosts to make them work

Tags: networking, router, node.js, npm

I used to have an **ASUS RT-AC86U** router and I could run `yarn add` or `npm install` without the need of modifying the `/etc/hosts`. Now I just bought a **D-Link EXO AX AX3200** router without modifying the default settings. However, yarn/ npm no longer work  due to failed network connection and timeout issues:

```
verbose 0.284464907 Performing "GET" request to "https://yarnpkg.com/latest-version".
[1/4] Resolving packages...
verbose 0.354563031 Performing "GET" request to "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@apollo%2fclient".
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
```

However, I can visit `https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@apollo%2fclient` on my browser.

I can also download a package directly with curl : `curl -o test.tgz -v https://registry.yarnpkg.com/vue-axios/-/vue-axios-2.1.4.tgz`. So I'm pretty sure the problem lies with the npm/yarn configuration.

The solution is adding these entries to `/etc/hosts` in order to make the commands work:

```
104.16.93.83   registry.npmjs.org
104.16.26.35   yarn.npmjs.org
```

The old router doesn't need to do this, so my experience with this D-link router is pretty bad. Do you have experience with this kind of problems with npm/yarn after replacing a router?

Here's the yarn config:

```
yarn config v1.22.19
info yarn config
{
  'version-tag-prefix': 'v',
  'version-git-tag': true,
  'version-commit-hooks': true,
  'version-git-sign': false,
  'version-git-message': 'v%s',
  'init-version': '1.0.0',
  'init-license': 'MIT',
  'save-prefix': '^',
  'bin-links': true,
  'ignore-scripts': false,
  'ignore-optional': false,
  registry: 'https://registry.yarnpkg.com',
  'strict-ssl': true,
  'user-agent': 'yarn/1.22.19 npm/? node/v19.9.0 linux x64'
}
info npm config
{
  prefix: '/home/me/.node_modules'
}
```

Updated:

My ISP doesn't allow me to enable IPV6. Here's the test result from https://test-ipv6.com/

[image]

```
$ traceroute to yarn.npmjs.org (2606:4700::6810:1423), 30 hops max, 80 byte packets

# 1  R32-CEEE.local (ROUTER_IP_V^_ADDRESS)  0.636 ms  0.595 ms  0.588 ms
  2  * * *
```

Comment: What results do you get from `traceroute -6 yarn.npmjs.org`, from `ip -6 route get 2606:4700::6810:ab63`, and from https://test-ipv6.com/?

Comment: I just updated the post with the results. My ISP doesn't allow me to enable IPV6, and the router admin page doesn't show any DNS info for IPV6. I could find DNS addresses for IPV4. I'm using arch linux.

Comment: I'm disabling IPV6 in Arch Linux with NetworkManager using this guide https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/IPv6#Disable_IPv6 . Will give you update later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your traceroute results, even though your ISP doesn't provide IPv6 connectivity, **your router advertises it anyway** and tells hosts to configure a default IPv6 route.

(I suspect that the router *also* thinks it has IPv6 connectivity from the ISP – if it did not, I'd expect to see traceroute just stop with "!X" "Unreachable" errors at 2nd hop – but instead it seems to be actually forwarding the packets *somewhere* further. That should not happen if the ISP was truly IPv4-only.)

The previous router didn't advertise itself as an IPv6 default gateway, so the OS just didn't try to look up IPv6 addresses of domains in the first place (recognizing that it's on an IPv4-only network). As the new router advertises both IPv4 and IPv6 default routes, programs now accordingly look up both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses.

Some programs such as curl or web browsers seem to work because they try *both* IPv4 and IPv6 concurrently (using the "Happy Eyeballs" algorithm) and use whichever address answers the fastest.

But most programs will try all the resolved addresses in sequence, with IPv6 addresses being first, which leads to long timeouts if the packets are just going to the void. Though normally the program should at least attempt to use another address instead of giving up outright.

(Again, it's strange that the router doesn't immediately respond with "Destination unreachable"; that would also avoid the timeouts and cause programs to directly fall back to IPv4 – but it seems like the ISP itself provides a v6 default route that doesn't work.)

Suggestions:

- Try to disable IPv6 *on the router* first, so that it won't advertise itself as a gateway. (You might be looking for the "SLAAC" setting.) Doing it centrally would be better, as the same problem affects all your LAN devices, not just the one computer.

  You can use `rdisc6` (from the ndisc6 package) to verify that either the Router Advertisements now show a "Router Lifetime" of zero – or that the router has stopped sending RAs at all.
- At the same time, check again whether you can *enable* IPv6 with your ISP. It could be that the D-Link router is being silly, but it could be that the ISP has indeed started providing IPv6 recently.
- Failing that, configure NetworkManager to not do automatic IPv6 configuration (e.g. set the `ipv6.method` parameter to something else). You don't need to go overboard with disabling IPv6 system-wide, it's enough to make sure it stops picking up an IPv6 address and a ::/0 route for your LAN.